# Regex to validate multiple email addresses

Tags: c#, regex

I have tried this code to validate multiple email addresses:

```
string email = "kamilar@recruit12.com; test@minh.com; test2@yahoo.com";

REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI = @"^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*((,|;)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*)*$";

Regex reg = new Regex(REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI);

var isOk = reg.IsMatch(email);
```

But it does not match - why?

Note that it matches with single address with this following expression:

```
@"^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*$"
```

Any help?

UPDATED:
I do NOT want to split the string to validate one by one! That's why I need to ask on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Why would you not validate the addresses one at a time??

Comment: @stuartd makes a good point. If you are absolutely sure you want to validate all at once, provide some examples that should and should not match please.

Comment: 99% sure you would want to validate one at a time.

Comment: As noted, split that string into an array and validate one at a time.  That will provide much more useful information.  Plus you probably don't want to invalidate the whole `to:` line, just dump the bad addresses out right?

Comment: @stuartd: I know it is easy to split to validate one at a time but that is the requirements from my situation. I want to understand why it does not work. That's why I need to post it to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my fault as the first email address does not passed the single email regex test so the multiple email regex test should fail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, you should be validating them one at a time.

```
string email = "kamilar@recruit12.com; test@minh.com; test2@yahoo.com";

string[] emailAddresses = email.Split(';').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToArray();

string REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI = @"^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*((,|;)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*)*$";

bool isOk = true;

foreach (string emailAddress in emailAddresses)
{
    Regex reg = new Regex(REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI);

    if (!reg.IsMatch(email))
    {
        isOk = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Invalid for loop, I'm guessing you're still updating it

Comment: and change that regex variable name pl

Comment: Missed some parentheses out there, and the `string` type! Sorry about that. Been writing VBA all day X-(

Comment: I know it is easier to split to validate one at a time but that is the requirements from my situation. I want to understand why it does not work. That's the reason why I post it to StackOverflow.

Comment: It doesn't work because that regex is for validating a single email address. Have you built a regex to validate multiple email addresses?

Answer (score 1):

split the string at the ';'

```
string email = "kamilar@recruit12.com; test@minh.com; test2@yahoo.com";
string[] emails = email.Split(';');
```

then create a method that returns the validity

```
private bool CheckAddress(string address){


    REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI = @"^\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*((,|;)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\'](\.)?)*[a-zA-Z0-9_%+~=$&*!#?\-\']@([a-zA-Z0-9-](\.)?)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})+\s*)*$";
    Regex reg = new Regex(REGEX_EMAIL_ADDRESS_MULTI);

    return reg.IsMatch(email);

}
```

now just loop through the addresses

```
for(int i = 0; i > emails.Length; i++){
    var isOK = CheckAddress(emails[i]);
}
```

This address is bad an invalidates the address string
[image: good multi address]

These addresses are OK and the string is allowed
[image: Bad address]

Comment: If I use this way I don't need to post it to SO to ask. I want the solution for RegEx, not having to split.

Comment: Your code does check multiple email addresses just fine. The trouble is that your first email address "kamilar@recruit12.com", causes a failure and devailidates the string.

Comment: good effort, I realized that was the problem as the first email address is not valid. Many thanks for your help!